# Preload unique related object in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

This works just fine and only performs one DB query:

```
qs = Blog.objects.filter(post=Subquery(
    Post.objects.filter(blog=OuterRef("pk"))
    .order_by("-date").values("pk")[:1]
))
for bt, pt in qs.values_list("title", "post__title"):
    print(f"The latest post in {bt} is about {pt}")
```

However, how can I have Django construct Blog and Post objects out of such a queryset without needing additional queries? Something like the following:

```
for blog in qs.select_related("post"):
    print(f"The latest post in {blog.title} is about {blog.post.title}")
```

Assume it’s not possible to reverse the queryset (Post.objects.select_related("blog")), because, for example, there are other related models that need the same treatment as Post.

Comment: No, although you can prefetch these yourself quite easily, which is basically how Django prefetches.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike Not at all easily because prefetch_related ignores filters on related objects (and outright refuses to work with FilteredRelation), and the problem is exacerbated if you need to pass the objects to something that expects a queryset so it’s hard to pass along extra information such as manually prefetched data.

Comment: I don't mean the `.prefetch_related` method, I mean doing what Django does itself when prefetching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, this works!

```
qs = Blog.objects.annotate(
    latest_post=FilteredRelation(
        "post",
        condition=Q(
            post=Subquery(
                Post.objects.filter(blog=OuterRef("pk"))
                .order_by("-seq")
                .values("pk")[:1]
            ),
        ),
    ),
).select_related("latest_post")

for blog in qs:
    print(f"The latest post in {blog.title} is about {blog.latest_post.title}")
```

This doesn’t actually require the condition to be unique:

```
for blog in Blog.objects.annotate(
    some_post=FilteredRelation("post"),
).select_related("some_post"):
    do_something(blog, blog.some_post)
    # will happen multiple times for the same blog
    # but blog.some_post will be different each time
```

Answer (score 0):

No, although you can prefetch these yourself quite easily, which is basically how Django prefetches. Indeed:

```
qs = Blog.objects.filter(
    post_id=Subquery(
        Post.objects.filter(blog=OuterRef('pk'))
        .order_by('-date')
        .values('pk')[:1]
    )
)

posts = {p.pk: p for p in Post.objects.filter(pk__in={q.post_id for q in qs})}
for q in qs:
    q.post = posts.get(q.post_id)

for b in qs:
    print(f'The latest post in {b.title} is about {b.post.title}')
```

We thus first collect all `.post_id`s of the `Blog`s, then make an extra query to get the corresponding `Post`s, and then attach for each `Blog` the corresponding `Post` object. It will attach `None` if it can not find the `Post`.

This of course is limited since you can not use other `QuerySet` methods: the `QuerySet` is evaluated and we patch the object with the `.post` attribute.

Comment: Doesn’t work with .iterator() at all, does it?

Comment: @RomanOdaisky: doesn't work with any extra method, since that constructs a *new* `QuerySet`. You could however let that work, for example through a proxy-object that each time when a new chunk is loaded, makes the "prefetch" for that chunk.